# BCC for email template not sending in Expresso Store

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

For some reason receipt emails are not being BCC'd to any address I enter in the email template. I've tried multiple addresses. Receipt comes through fine to customer, though.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  The emails are landing in my gmail account, but a company that I'm working with who are BCC'd are not. I suspect it's the restrictions on their mail server.  Perhaps it's time to hack the plugin to allow response emails to send to multiple addresses instead of BCC.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when this happens it's getting caught in a spam filter (e.g. many spam filters will catch mail if the "from address" and "to address" are the same). The BCC is sent exactly the same way as the customer email, so if the customer email is coming through it's highly unlikely to be Store/EE's fault.

Comment: I got this resolved.  Apparently the hosting company I'm using had the mx records on the domain screwed up so, the emails were coming in, just not getting sent anywhere.